# Ajax requests to local server with phonegap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, cordova

I have trouble making ajax requests to a local `Rails server` using `Phonegap`.  I have a universal whitelist in config.xml for outgoing urls as so:

```
<access origin="*"/>
```

and I have the android app with Phonegap set to load the signin page on the rails app like so:

```
super.loadUrl("http://10.0.2.2:3000/signin")
```

and I have no problem accessing any of the pages served by the local rails server.  However I cannot get ajax requests to go through, the Rails server logs never show a request being received. An example ajax request:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (localStorage.getItem("auth_token") != null) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://10.0.2.2:3000/api/v2/api_login.json',
            data: {"token": localStorage.getItem("auth_token")},
            success: function (data) {
                alert("token saved");
                window.location = data.url
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        alert("no token");
    }
});
```

I have also tried setting the url domain in the ajax request to both `127.0.0.1:3000` and  `www.lvh.me:3000` with no luck.

If I access the pages through a browser and not Phonegap everything works fine.  If I push the code to heroku and access the url to point to heroku everything works fine.  The problem seems to be submitting ajax requests to the local server.

Comment: Is your "local server" accessible from the internet? (ie has a public url)

Comment: heroku is an online service. if your server can't be reached from internet heroku can't see it. It's not a phonegap issue, you would not have this issue if you built your app on a real device or in android sdk emulator.

Comment: Sorry my first post may not have been clear.  If I am running a server locally (127.0.0.1:3000), and running an android emulator in android studio with phonegap, I can connect to the local server fine, but I cannot submit ajax requests to the local server, they do not seem to go through.  If I run the server via heroku, and point the android emulator to heroku, ajax works fine.  The issue is getting ajax requests to go through from phonegap to the local server.

Also if I use firefox instead of phonegap ajax requests to the local server are successful.